# Can I extend a base class and cast the base to the extension

Tags: c#

I have write this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Foo m_oFoo = new Foo() { 
            S1 = "N"
        };

        List<Foo> m_List = new List<Foo>();
        m_List.Add(m_oFoo);

        IFoo m_oIFoo = (IFoo)m_List[0];
        m_oIFoo.S2 = "C";

        Response.Write(m_oIFoo.S1);
        Response.Write(m_oIFoo.S2);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public Foo()
    {

    }
}

public class IFoo: Foo
{
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public IFoo(){}
}
```

But the compiler say's "Unable to cast object of type 'Foo' on type 'IFoo'."
How I can Cast Foo to Foo1 without declare a caster with all Foo methods because this is an example, Foo has more than 100 methods.

thanks for the help

Comment: Calling a class something with an `I` prefix doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Having a prefix of `I` is standard convention for an interface.  Please don't use it for a sub-class of a type, you're completely violating people's expectations.

Comment: You cannot cast an instance of a base class to one of its sub-classes, because it WILL NOT implement that sub-class, by definition. Please explain your actual business problem in more detail so that a technically appropriate solution can be developed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can Cast Foo to Foo1

You can't.  Ever.  The object really is a `Foo` object, not an `IFoo`, so no cast will ever succeed.  You need to "convert" the object, which is a very different thing.  You need to create a new `IFoo` object based on the data provided in a `Foo` instance.  One way of doing this is though a constructor in `IFoo` that accepts a `Foo` object:

```
public class IFoo: Foo
{
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public IFoo(){}
    public IFoo(Foo other)
    {
        S1 = other.S1;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
IFoo m_oIFoo = new IFoo(m_List[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a base class into one of it's derived (extended) classes. This is pretty intuitive if you think about the process of extending a class in general. When extending a class, the extended class might add members which will not be present in the base class so when if the compiler allowed the cast then potentially disastrous things could happen!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no built-in way of doing it. Best bet is to use either reflection to retrieve all the properties that exist in both classes and set the values that way, or possibly serialize the object and then deserialize it into the other type.

Neither way is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a base class to a subclass, but you can do something similar with a  [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

```
public class IFoo: Foo
{
    ...

    public static explicit operator IFoo(Foo foo)  // explicit byte to digit conversion operator
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast from base class to derived class. Instead, try writing an `explicit` converter and use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map all the properties.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please refrain from having capital first I in your classes, that is usually used for interfaces. Second of all, you cannot cast "upwards" because IFoo inherits Foo, not the other way around.

Think about it in this way: IFoo is a Foo, but not the other way round.

You can, however, rewrite it to this:

```
IFoo m_oIFoo = m_List[0] as IFoo; // this might be null now
if (m_oIFoo != null)
{
    m_oIFoo.S2 = "C";

    Response.Write(m_oIFoo.S1);
    Response.Write(m_oIFoo.S2);
}
```

Use the [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator for casting, but be aware that it can return null.

Comment: This will just result in the variable always being `null`, since it will never ever be an `IFoo`.

Comment: But it can be since List parameter is covariant.

Comment: No, the list parameter is *not* covariant. It is in fact *invariant*.  Finally, we can see all of the values added to the list, they're hard coded, and they're not `IFoo` instances, it's a `Foo` instance.  He needs to *convert* the object, not *cat* the object.